# Data loading limit oracle apex 5

Tags: apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using data load page in oracle apex 5, when I load my .csv file which contains more than 90 columns and 1,000 rows.. I've noticed that I only can see 45 colums and 500 rows in the report..

Can I change that limit for rows and columns? where?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is NO, apex collection doesn't allow such number of columns.

Comment: Is there another way to load a .csv file with more than 45 columns?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for loadig more than 45 Columns to a collection, Anton Scheffer used this method in his apex Plugin [excel2collections](https://github.com/antonscheffer/excel2collections) where he would use the first Columns to identify a single row in the collection.

> Load more than 50 columns. Because we can store only 50 varchar2
>   columns in a APEX collection, columns above 50 are loaded in a second
>   row. Attribute N001 stores the row number, attribute N002 stores the
>   column number of C001.

That way you could identify one row of data by the N002 Column e.g.

```
N001 C001 C002 C003 C004 C005 C006 .. C050
  01 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] .. [  ] 
  51 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] .. [  ]
 101 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] .. [  ]
  01 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] .. [  ] 
  51 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] .. [  ]
 101 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] .. [  ]
```